# Setting UIToolBar programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am trying to create a toolbar programmatically in a class that subclasses ABPersonViewController.
Here is what I have done.

```
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self     action:@selector(onToolbarTapped:)];
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: customItem, nil];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
//[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:items]];
self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

The toolbar doesn't appear. What am I doing wrong here.

Edit: I have edited my code as follows

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[[UIToolbar alloc] init]autorelease];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 372, self.view.frame.size.width, 45);
UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:unblockContact style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered   target:self     action:@selector(onToolbarTapped:)];
customItem.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:customItem, nil];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[customItem release];
```

How can I make the barbuttonitem occupy the entire toolbar. The user shouldn't feel that there is a barbuttonitem on the toolbar. Could I do this way, or is there an alternate way?
Help needed. Thanks.

Comment: does it generate an error or simply you are not reaching to view the toolbar or buttonItem?

Comment: As of now now errors generated. But the toolbar is not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

UIToolbar is a subclass of UIView, you should add it as any other view, following method is what am successfully using,

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 45);
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithObjects...]];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Comment: I just have one button in the toolbar. So it should fill the entire toolbar

Comment: so you have now your toolbar with one button but its aspect is default, right?

Comment: Yes. I need to have a toolbar with one barbuttonitem, which fills the entire toolbar. One shouldn't able to distinguish the barbuttonitem from the toolbar

Comment: Is it possible with the UIBarButtonItem